# PHP: STDOUT vs php://STDOUT

Tags: php, io, protocols, wrapper

What is the difference between **STDOUT** and **php://STDOUT** in PHP?

```
fwrite(STDOUT, ...);
```

vs

```
$StdOut = fopen('php://stdout', 'w');
fwrite($StdOut, ...);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The former is file descriptor 1, the second is a copy of FD1 in a new FD (e.g. 3).

Answer (score 2):

`STDOUT` is only avaliable in CLI sapi